# Microsoft Graph Application Permissions with Security Groups?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We've been looking into integrating out O365 subscription more with our internal applications, and the Microsoft Graph set of APIs seems to fit our needs, but we have hit some security issues.

We would be integrating this into Windows Services, to handle Calendar bookings first. We put together a prototype using the Application level Permissions, but were told we could not use it (in our company) because it granted access to Users' calendars which would be considered secure and the application should never have access to. We then attempted to switch to delegate permissions, and then delegate access to the calendars we wanted, but the downfall here is the login prompt, which causes issues when you want to run this application unattended.

The Questions:
1) Is there a way to limit the Users in the Application level Permissions? Maybe connect the application to a security group instead of all users?

2) Or, is there a way to use the delegate permissions without the Login Prompt, so we can do it all through code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is there a way to limit the Users in the Application level
>   Permissions?

No.

> Maybe connect the application to a security group instead of all
>   users?

No such configuration in the [**AAD apps**](https://aad.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/RegisteredApps) now. Nor the **apps.devs** apps.

> 2) Or, is there a way to use the delegate permissions without the
>   Login Prompt, so we can do it all through code?

No. I see you have tried the Windows Service, it should be this [auth flow](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service). But background services cannot access all resources.

Above is for your current questions. And I need more background about your internal app, so i can try further assist you.